# Weird Behavior of Table and Sequence

Tags: evaluation, list-manipulation, sequence

I'm writing a function that constructs a multidimensional array (that is, nested lists) using `Table`. The dimension of the array varies according to the argument to the function, so the number of arguments to `Table` will vary. So I use `Sequence` to provide some of the arguments to `Table`. But it fails, and I see a weird behavior.

For example, if I type the code

```
    Table[{i, j}, {i, 3}, {j, 4}]
```

then I get

```
    {{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}}}
```

Now, I'm trying to provide all but the first argument to `Table` dynamically, so I use `Sequence`. I try it first on an expression with the head "`Table`" replaced by something undefined, just to make sure that the arguments are evaluated correctly.

```
    SomeHead[{i, j}, Sequence @@ MapThread[List, {{i, j}, {3, 4}}]]
```

evaluates to

```
    SomeHead[{i, j}, {i, 3}, {j, 4}]
```

which is identical to the first code I wrote here, except with the head `Table` replaced with the undefined symbol `Somehead`. But if I now write

```
    Table[{i, j}, Sequence @@ MapThread[List, {{i, j}, {3, 4}}]]
```

which should give the first result above, it instead gives an error:

```
    Table::nliter: Non-list iterator Sequence@@MapThread[List,{{i,j},{3,4}}] at position 2 does not evaluate to a real numeric value.
    Table[{i, j}, Sequence @@ MapThread[List, {{i, j}, {3, 4}}]]
```

Why is this happening? And how can I write `Table` with dynamic number of arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Attributes[Table]
```

> {HoldAll, Protected}

`HoldAll` is a problem because it prevents your `Sequence` from being evaluated before `Table` is evaluated.

You could insert `Evaluate` or use `Apply`:

```
Table[{i, j}, Evaluate[Sequence @@ MapThread[List, {{i, j}, {3, 4}}]]]
Table[{i, j}, ##] & @@ MapThread[List, {{i, j}, {3, 4}}]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}},  
>  {{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}},  
>  {{3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much! :D

Comment: I personally prefer the second version; it's usually less confusing to do.